# AS 2.0 dynamic Text in Movieclip

Tags: flash, actionscript-2

I'm using ActionScript 2.0 and I do not have control of dynamic text inside movie clips. I have a movie clip named 'Glass' and dynamic text named 'Glass_ID'
I want `Glass_ID` Value become `Glass_ID01` when clicked the button named 'btn' but it doesn's work 
how to i'm solve it?

```
on(press){this.Glass.Glass_ID.text ="Glass_ID01"}
```

Comment: Is the button inside the movieclip?

Comment: No. button and movieclip in same  layer

Comment: So, you can't use "this", try _root or _level0 (or the level you're in)

Comment: Like this?

on (press) {
 _level0..Glass.Glass_ID.text = "Glass_ID01";
}
or
on (press) {
 _root..Glass.Glass_ID.text = "Glass_ID01";
}

Comment: Ok, but only one dot after _level0 or _root (or the mc you're in)

Comment: oh. thank you. it's working!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If "Glass" is not inside the button this won't work, you must set the correct path, eg.

```
on(press){_level0.Glass.Glass_ID.text ="Glass_ID01"}
```

or from the timeline:

```
btn.onPress = function(){
   _level0.Glass.Glass_ID.text ="Glass_ID01"
}
```

(of course, you should change that `_level0` with `_root` or a container movieclip, whatever applies to your situation).

Disclaimer: last time I used Flash it was 2011!   :-)